# Java - Change int to ascii

Tags: java, int

Is there a way for java to convert int's to ascii symbols?

Answer (score 81):

Do you want to convert `int`s to `char`s?:

```
int yourInt = 33;
char ch = (char) yourInt;
System.out.println(yourInt);
System.out.println(ch);
// Output:
// 33
// !
```

Or do you want to convert `int`s to `String`s?

```
int yourInt = 33;
String str = String.valueOf(yourInt);
```

Or what is it that you mean?

Comment: int yourInt = 33;
String str = String.valueOf(yourInt);
what is the output?

Answer (score 18):

If you first convert the int to a char, you will have your ascii code.

For example:

```
    int iAsciiValue = 9; // Currently just the number 9, but we want Tab character
    // Put the tab character into a string
    String strAsciiTab = Character.toString((char) iAsciiValue);
```

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to convert an int to ASCII (depending on your needs) but here is a way to convert each integer byte to an ASCII character:

```
private static String toASCII(int value) {
    int length = 4;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        builder.append((char) ((value >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

For example, the ASCII text for "TEST" can be represented as the byte array:

```
byte[] test = new byte[] { (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0x53, (byte) 0x54 };
```

Then you could do the following:

```
int value = ByteBuffer.wrap(test).getInt(); // 1413829460
System.out.println(toASCII(value)); // outputs "TEST"
```

...so this essentially converts the 4 bytes in a 32-bit integer to 4 separate ASCII characters (one character per byte).

Answer (score 4):

You can convert a number to ASCII in java. example converting a number 1 (base is 10) to ASCII.

```
char k = Character.forDigit(1, 10);
System.out.println("Character: " + k);
System.out.println("Character: " + ((int) k));
```

Output:

```
Character: 1
Character: 49
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Character.toString( yourAsciiNumber )
```

Use [`Character#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)), not `char`. Like this:

```
String result = Character.toString( yourAsciiNumber ) ;
```

Example:

```
Character.toString( 97 )   // LATIN SMALL LETTER A
```

> a

```
Character.toString( 128_567 )   // FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK
```

> 

## `char` is legacy

The `char` type in Java is legacy, and is essentially broken. As a [16-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16-bit_computing) value, `char` is incapable of representing most  characters defined by [Unicode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

This succeeds:

```
System.out.println( Character.toString( 128_567 ));  // Unicode code points handle full-range of Unicode characters.
```

> 

This fails:

```
System.out.println( ( char ) 128_567 );  // `char` fails with most Unicode characters.
```

See [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/zVXbpt).

## Code point

Use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers to represent individual letters.

[US-ASCII](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a subset of Unicode. So, any US-ASCII number (0-127) is also a Unicode code point (0-1,114,111).

To change a code point number to a `String` object containing a single character, call [`Character#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)).

```
String x = Character.toString( 97 ) ;
```

> a

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/yGV08C).

Answer (score 1):

In fact in the last answer
     String strAsciiTab = Character.toString((char) iAsciiValue);
the essential part is (char)iAsciiValue which is doing the job (Character.toString useless)

Meaning the first answer was correct actually
    char ch = (char) yourInt;

if in yourint=49 (or 0x31), ch will be '1'

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you really want to use [Integer.toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int)) to convert an integer to its corresponding String value. If you are dealing with just the digits 0-9, then you could use something like this:

```
private static final char[] DIGITS =
    {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

private static char getDigit(int digitValue) {
   assertInRange(digitValue, 0, 9);
   return DIGITS[digitValue];
}
```

Or, equivalently:

```
private static int ASCII_ZERO = 0x30;

private static char getDigit(int digitValue) {
  assertInRange(digitValue, 0, 9);
  return ((char) (digitValue + ASCII_ZERO));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is using type casting:

```
public char toChar(int c) {
    return (char)c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to get integer and just use the casting operator
Ex

```
int num = 33;
System.out.println((char) num);    //Outputs 33

//if you want to find the integer value of character instead.
//Just do the reverse

char ch = '%';
System.out.println((int) ch);
```