# Converting a int to char

Tags: java, ascii

I am looking to convert numbers to their corresponding letter in the alphabet.

Comment: [Try this Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328996/java-change-int-to-ascii) Question was already asked to stackoverflow

Comment: The term alphabet is not very precise and the system of a number's corresponding letter is unclear. I am familiar with the English alphabet of 26 letters from to A-Z and the idea of numbering them 1 to 26. However, Java uses Unicode for text datatypes. Unicode has at least two forms for those letters (lowercase and uppercase) as well as a number of specialized scripts with some or all of those letters. It also has its own [numbering system](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) for every character (usually written in hexadecimal like U+0041). Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

As seen [here](http://www.asciitable.com) alphabetical characters start from either 65 or 97 (depending on capitalization) so you just add either 64 or 96 to your value and then just cast it to a char.

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
int TargetNumber = rand.nextInt(25) + 1;
char TargetChar = (char) (TargetNumber+64);
```

Comment: I want the corresponding  lowercase letter so i add 96? Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes, `char TargetChar = (char) (TargetNumber+96);` will give you the lowercase char

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
int TargetNumber = rand.nextInt(25) + 1;
char c = (char)(TargetNumber+96);
```

This adds `96` to the generated value, and then *type casts* it into a `char`. This works for `a-z`. To make it through `A-Z` replace `96`, by `64`.

Answer (score -2):

i think you can do this:

```
char a = (char)20;
```