# Reading Int value of bytes from inputStream

Tags: java, android, byte

I am trying to read the ASCII value of bytes in the inputstream. I have the following code

```
 int bd = 0;
 byte[] buffer = new byte[260];
 while (true) {
     try {
          if ((bd = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
              Log.d("TAG", "Number of bytes from stream" + bd);
           }
```

In order to read the value of bytes. I tried one of the following method from this SO example [read byte value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536054/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string-and-vice-versa).

```
String s = new String(buffer,StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

System.out.println("data from buffer s : " + s);
Result of s:"/9AAAAAAAAAAAAA=="
System.out.println("data from buffer s : " + parseInt(s)); -- error

String s2 = new String(buffer);
System.out.println("data from buffer s2: " + s2);
Result of s2: �@���������������
```

How can I get the ASCII values which are int ? I tried to convert string into Int using `parseInt(s)` but I get thrown into `NumberFormatException error`

Comment: you want a byte value  as int (in an `int` variable)? you want the int value that corresponds to 4 bytes? ...? maybe some example in terms of input value and expected output could help

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I would like to get the ascii values

Comment: like: *I have, for example, a String `"/A" and want the respective ASCII values  `int[] { 47, 65 }` .* ?

Comment: yes I am looking for that. But the conversion leads to `NumberFormatexception error`

Comment: then I didn't understand the "*bytes in the inputstream*" part?? nor the base 64 one?  you can get each `char` of the String (`toCharArray()` or `charAt()`) which are actually the code of that character and be cast to `int`(`char ch = ...; int ascii = (int) ch;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can I get the byte values which are int ?

Convert int to string first

```
 int a = 454545454;
        String data = String.valueOf(a);
        try {
            byte[] bytesdata = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

on your question change

Replace all non-digit with blank: the remaining string contains only digits.

```
Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""))
```

Now for further have look [Get ASCII from int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20966226/5110595)

Comment: I have reframed my question. Will it work similarly ?

Comment: No,Now your question is completely different.

Comment: sorry for the trouble. I misunderstood. Reading ASCII values leads to that error

Comment: @cantona_7 its ok, i edit my post, check it and let me know its useful or not.

Answer (score 1):

what are you trying to do here? print only the number 9 from the given string?   if so you can catch the number format exception and handle it.

or are you trying to print that ascii code for the string "/9AAAAAAAAAAAAA=="?

As Carlos said above, if you have each char in the loop, just cast it to an int and you will get the underlying value in memory.

```
    char b1 = 'f';
    System.out.println("data from buffer s2: " + (int) b1);


    "data from buffer s2: 102"
```

Comment: yes, I was looking for that exactly !! sorry for misleading

Comment: actually this is not an answer, it is a question! @cantona_7 "that exactly what? this ans.. question has two options

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger ofcourse I understand that. I just edited my question and alos the method I tried

Comment: sorry @Carlos Heuberger , I did't have enough internet points to allow me to comment on the original qn.