# How to cast an object which consists of integer to corresponding character in ascii?

Tags: java, object, debugging, casting, character

I tried

```
'''
Object b = 3;
char cdd = (Character) b;
System.out.print(cdd);
'''
```

but it has the following error. 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Character
How can I fix it?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328996/java-change-int-to-ascii) what you need?

Comment: By casting to Integer, as the error message tells you.

Comment: Cast to `int` first (the unboxed version of `java.lang.Integer`) Then don't cast to `Character` but to `char` to prevent unnecessary boxing and immediately unboxing

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

First cast to **int** and after that to **char**

```
Object b = 98;
int cdd = (int) b;
System.out.println(cdd);
System.out.println((char) cdd);
```

Output is

```
98
b
```